# FineUploader onSubmit not being called

Tags: fine-uploader

Using FineUploader 3.8.2 to upload PDF files to S3, I am running into an interesting issue and not sure if perhaps I'm just using the wrong syntax or not understanding how the options should work for fineUploader.  Here is my code...

```
var uploader = $('#fine-uploader-box').fineUploaderS3({
  debug: true,
  button: $('#choose-file-button'),
  multiple: false,
  autoUpload: false,
  request: {
   endpoint: '(no url yet because I need to know about the file before I can construct an S3 PUT url)'
  },
  callbacks: {
    onSubmit: function(id, name){ // function to get real endpoint url goes here },
    onSubmitted: function(id, name){ // or function to get real endpoint url goes here }
  },
  validation: {
    allowedExtensions: ['pdf']
  }
});
```

What I am trying to do is just get a function to run once my file has been added to the list but I am not seeing the onSubmit (or onSubmitted) firing.

My goal is to have that function do some ajax-y stuff and return some information in which I will use to facilitate the rest of the upload process including getting a specialized S3 PUT url from my server to send my upload to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are using the syntax for the non-jQuery uploader, but you are using the jQuery uploader. Check out the below:

```js
var uploader = $('#fine-uploader-box').fineUploaderS3({
  debug: true,
  button: $('#choose-file-button'),
  multiple: false,
  autoUpload: false,
  request: {
   endpoint: '(no url yet because I need to know about the file before I can construct an S3 PUT url)'
  },
  validation: {
    allowedExtensions: ['pdf']
  }
}).on('submit', function (event, fileId, fileName) {
    alert("File id: "+fileId);
}).on('submitted', function (event, fileId, fileName) {
    alert("File id: "+fileId);    
});
```

Comment: Heh, you'd be surprised how many times that mistake has been made. Probably means I'll have to update the documentation to make it more clear. :)